# Error accessing large data frame

Tags: r

I'm reading a dataframe and I have the message `fread(273) failed on DBF file` repeated many times. The reading code is simple:

```
dataset <- read.dbf(fl, as.is = FALSE)
```

The dbf file I'm reading is the sum of a number of dbf files that contain 873.259 in total, as I counted them in the process. I have used both rbind and ldply.

I have checked the size limitations of the dataframe but it doesn't seem a problem in this case. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Sorry, when I said 873.259 I meant rows.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example. What package does `read.dbf` come from (foreign or spsurvey) How have you used rbind and ldply? In what what is fl the sum of a number of dbf files?